# What are the rules of transferring the registration of a vehicle from one state to another in India?

Tags: india, vehicle-registration

When a vehicle is registered in a Regional Transport Office (RTO) in a state in India, one needs to get a No Objection Certificate (NOC) from that office before moving the vehicle permanently out of the jurisdiction of that RTO (and state). The NOC, as I could understand, certifies that the vehicle doesn't have any criminal offenses or pending fines in that RTO, and therefore a new registration process may be initiated. However, it is not clear what documents are needed in order to get that NOC. The list of the Ministry of Road Transport and Highways mentions

1. Address proof
2. Form 28
3. Insurance certificate
4. Registration certificate

My confusion is that this doesn't mention any clearance from the police or National Crimes Bureau. Are we to assume that no additional documents are needed for this NOC application?

The NOC application is possible to do [online](https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahaneservice/usermanual/selectedservice/noc/). However, I want to remove the eventuality that I fill the form, pay the fees, and show up with those documents, and at the RTO I'm asked for more documents like the ones from the police or crime bureau.

**Edit after going through the process:**

All of the above are needed, but the crucial thing is the road tax certificate. This is typically mentioned in the original purchase receipt of the vehicle, which you must get from the first owner of the vehicle if you are purchasing it from him/her. Without this, the new RTO will not know (on paper) what road taxes have been paid while purchasing the vehicle, and will redo the calculation for the entire life of the vehicle (which is stupid and meaningless in my view, but that's what it is) which may be way more than you'd expect. Yes, if the showroom from where the car was purchased is still operational, then you might ask them for a duplicate invoice, but after 2-3 years after the sale, no showroom maintains that record in India (forget about digital copies).

Comment: Associated question concerning re-registering the vehicle in the new state: 
  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67428/how-to-do-a-vehicle-re-registration-interstate-transfer-in-india

Answer (score 1):

**What are the rules..**

You, as the applicant, make a declaration on your RTO form 28 (aka CMV form 28 found [here](https://parivahan.gov.in/parivahan/en/content/vehicle-registration)) to include what, if any, tax demands or loans etc are outstanding along with the consent of any financiers for those loans etc.

The RTO will then check with the police to see if the vehicle is stolen or involved in criminality before issuing you with a NOC.

Note that your list of documents seems to be incomplete:

- Name and address proof of the Registered Owner (photo ID)
- Name and address proof of the buyer (if applicable)
- Original Registration Certificate of the vehicle
- Pencil print of the Engine Chassis
- Pollution Control Certificate
- Road Tax Certificate
- Insurance certificate (if applicable)
- Permit and fitness certificate (applicable for commercial vehicles)

(This list is an amalgamation taken from
[here](https://babatrucks.com/rto-forms/form-28) and [here](https://www.bankbazaar.com/driving-licence/no-objection-certificate.html) - I've not gone through this process, but I assume it's probably better to have too much than not enough.)