# How to do a Vehicle Re-Registration (Interstate Transfer) in India?

Tags: india, vehicle-registration

This question considers only the permanent move of a vehicle from one state to another in India. This earlier [question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/67426/38902) discussed the process of getting the clearance from the originating Regional Transport Office (RTO) so that the vehicle can be re-registered in the destination state. Suppose the NOC is available and the other documents are in place. What is the procedure to get the vehicle re-registered in the destination state? Is there an online facility for the application?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your vehicle re-registered in your new state, you need to take the following to the new RTO:

- Your vehicle (which the RTO will inspect)
- Your NOC from your previous state (*or if you're selling it, 3 copies of the Form 28*)
- The original previous registration certificate
- Form 20 to apply for registration
- Form 27 to apply for a new registration mark
- Proof of your address
- Proof of your valid insurance
- Proof of your valid Pollution Under Control Certificate.
- Your PAN Card or Form 60 and 61.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.godigit.com/traffic-rules/transfer-of-vehicle-registration-from-one-state-to-another-state.amp.html))

[Here](https://parivahan.gov.in/parivahan/en/content/vehicle-registration) are links to various forms.

As the vehicle and documents need to be inspected by the RTO, it seems that re-registering a vehicle on-line may not be an option. But you may wish to ask this question at the old RTO.