# Can I get national permit for my personal car in India?

Tags: india, vehicle, vehicle-registration, car

I recently bought a new car (2 weeks ago). It is still in temporary registration. I am transferring to a different state (for around 2 years). Can I get national permit or some kind of permit instead of re-registering my car in the new state?

Is there any better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not for 1+ years

See [section 47](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_30_42_00009_198859_1517807326286&sectionId=28320&sectionno=47&orderno=50) of the Motor Vehicle Act 1988:

> (1) When a motor vehicle registered in one State has been kept in another State, for a period exceeding twelve months, the owner of the vehicle shall, within such period and in such form containing such particulars as may be prescribed by the Central Government, apply to the registering authority, within whose jurisdiction the vehicle then is, for the assignment of a new registration mark and shall present the certificate of registration to that registering authority:
>
> [...]

Related: [1](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/67452/35069) [2](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/67435/35069)